# Text looks Blurred and cheap In Android Hybrid App using ionic framework

Tags: android, css, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app, ionic-framework

I am Learning [Ionic Framework](http://ionicframework.com/) (Hybrid mobile app ui framework on top of cordova).

i am following a docs and learning a app.

i found the text blur issue in android. where some text looks much clear and some text becomes blurred. i am debugging mobile web view and mobile chrome through chrome developer tools on windows 8.

here is the screenshots of blur. please take a look.
[image: Image Using Google Chrome On Nexus 7 screen 1]

For make Closer Comparison I have make the same background color and same foreground color.here is this image.[image: Image Using Google Chrome On Nexus 7 screen 2]

I have tried text shadow none, also tried to remove any transforms on parent elements , but nothing worked in my case.

please help me.

in case needed ....  i am working on windows 8.1 using visual studio 2013.
and using ionic-framework for hybrid mobile app. my device is nexus 7 2012(android 4.4.4)

Anybody have idea how can i remove this text blur issue?

Comment: same here. do you have any solution ?

Comment: @vzhen if you apply translate z (0)   then the problem comes. if removes translate z , then it back to clear , but we cannot remove transalate z on ionic framework/ cordova

Comment: Have you found any solution of this problem for Ionic framework?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 4):

In my case I have found the following solutions for this problem:

1. Check code for html errors (brackets, etc.)
2. Experiment with your css classes, for example using padding="true" instead of class="padding" on ion-content fixed all issues in my case

Comment: That was it for me. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I added the following code to custom CSS which helped:

```
div.scroll.padding {
      -webkit-transform: initial !important;
}
```

This transformation caused the problem:

```
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px) scale(1);
```